# Reading from a text file into an array - getting "nulls"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm reading from a file and copying that into an array. My file has five lines of text, a sentence each. I get my output "Array size is 5" but nothing after that. If I do add a print line of the array, it gives me 5 nulls...

Can someone help explain what I did wrong? Thanks!

```js
public static int buildArray() throws Exception
    {  
        System.out.println("BuildArray is starting ");
    
        java.io.File textFile; // declares a variable of type File
        textFile = new java.io.File ("textFile.txt"); //reserves the memory
        
        Scanner input = null;
            try 
            {
               input = new Scanner(textFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Exception in method"); 
                System.exit(0);
            }

            int arraySize = 0;
            while(input.hasNextLine()) 
               { 
                    arraySize = arraySize + 1;
                    if (input.nextLine() == null)
                        break;
               }
        System.out.println("Array size is " + arraySize);

        // Move the lines into the array
        String[] linesInRAM = new String[arraySize];// reserve the memory
        int count = 0;
        if (input.hasNextLine())
           { 
                while(count < arraySize) 
                {
                    System.out.println("test");
                    linesInRAM[count] = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println(linesInRAM[count]);
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You never reset the scanner, so it's till at the end of the file...

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
    int count = 0;
    if (input.hasNextLine())
```

The above `hasNextLine` will always be false as you have already read all the way through the file.

Either reset the scanner to the beginning of the file, or use a dynamic list e.g. `ArrayList` to add the elements to.

Answer (score 0):

My Java is a bit rusty, but the basic gist of my answer is that you should create a new Scanner object so that it reads from the beginning of the file again. This is the easiest way to "reset" to the beginning.

Your code is currently not working because when you call `input.nextLine()` you're actually incrementing the scanner, and thus at the end of that first `while()` loop `input` is sitting at the end of the file, so when you call `input.nextLine()` again it returns `null`.

```
Scanner newScanner = new Scanner(textFile);
```

Then in the bottom of your code, your loop should look like this instead:

```
if (newScanner.hasNextLine())
    { 
        while(count < arraySize) 
            {
                System.out.println("test");
                linesInRAM[count] = newScanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(linesInRAM[count]);
                count = count + 1;
            }
    }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you thank you. Now it's working. I didn't quite realize scanner worked like that, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Sure! Be sure to click that checkmark and/or the up arrow ;)